# Excel won't open large xml files

Tags: php, xml, excel

I have this php script that generates an xml file from a database. It works very well with small files. The table has 53 columns.

Excel opens easily a file with 7000 rows (file size 20Mb) but over around 14000 rows (file size 40Mb), Excel won't open it as a table (it says import html error and that the file has a table problem) but suggest to open it as a text file with obviously is not what I want.

I have the latest version of Excel for Mac. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's a snippet of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<Worksheet ss:Name="XXXX">
<Table>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Id</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Postal Code</Data></Cell>
        .....
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">43653</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">347</Data></Cell>
        .....
    </Row>
</Table>
```

Comment: How sure are you that it is related to number of rows and not some poorly encoded content in the XML ?

Comment: For sure but why does it open a file generate with the same code of 7000 rows but not 14000 and yes I've checked the formatting.

Comment: Based on the namespaces you could quite well have the xml in the Excel 2003 SpreadsheetML flavour and therefore could be hitting limits inherent to an older version of file specification *even though* you have the latest version of Excel. Check you `xmlns` attributes again this spec: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpreadsheetML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I had above creating pure xml files is not a good one since this is based on the standards in Excel 2003. I found a PHP library called Spout that is extremely fast and can read and write huge Excel files: [Spout PHP Library on Github](https://github.com/box/spout)

Answer (score 1):

Please check your Excel version,

versions of Excel up to **7.0** had a limitation in the size of their data sets of **16K (214 = 16384)** rows.

Versions 8.0 through 11.0 could handle

> 64K (216 = 65536) rows and 256 columns (28 as label 'IV').

Version 12.0 can handle

> 1M (220 = 1048576) rows, and 16384 (214 as label 'XFD') columns.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I already have the latest version.